# why is a homomorphism a cover space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose we have a homomorphism  $p:E \rightarrow X.$ 
Suppose $x \in X$, then we choose $U=E$. This means we have
$p^{-1}(U)=E$ and $P|_E: E \rightarrow^{\cong} X.$

Here is my question:
How do we know $P^{-1}(U)=E$ is  a disjoint union of open sets?

Comment: Homomorphism of what?

Comment: we are working in topological spaces

Comment: So $p$ is a continuous map? Because the word "hom**e**omorphism" kind of corresponds to "isomorphism".

Comment: yes, I assume you are right

Comment: @usere5225321 disjoint union of copies of $U$ means a space homeomorphic to $F \times U$ where $F$ is a discrete space. Here, you can take $F = \{pt\}$ so an homeomorphism is indeed a special case of a covering space.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet can you give me more details, I am confused

Comment: Sure, could you please copy the exact definition of a covering space you have ?

Comment: Let $p: E \rightarrow B$ be a continuous surjective map. The open set $U$ of $B$ is said to be evenly covered iby $p$ if the inverse image $p^{-1}(U)$ can be written as the union of disjoint open sets $V_{\alpha}$ in E such that for each $\alpha$, the restriction of $p$ to $V_{\alpha}$ is a homeomorphism of $V_{\alpha}$ onto U.

Comment: Good, now taking $\alpha =1$ (so only one index) and $V_1 = E$ I claim hat $U = X$ is evenly covered. And if $U$ is evenly covered, any open $U' \subset U$ is also evenly covered so it follows that $p : E \to X$ is a covering space. Is this clear ?

Comment: okay, so we have to restrict ourself to an open $U'$ in order for this to work, right?

Comment: Ok in fact there is no need of introducing $U'$ : the definition of a covering space $p : E \to B$ is that for all $b \in B$ there is a neighborhood $U_b$ of $b$ which is evenly covered. Here we can take $U_b = X$ as $X$ is already evenly covered.

Comment: A good exercise for understanding definitions.